# No Script Configured for URL 'AGI://localhost/xxx.agi'

Tags: java, asterisk, agi

Getting the below error when trying to initiate call.

```
<SIP/xx.xxx.xxx.xx-00000000>AGI Rx << VERBOSE "No script configured for URL 'AGI://localhost/xxx.agi' (script 'xxx.agi')" 1
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: I dont see any relation to java here?

Comment: @GyroGearless, it's written in java and mapping is done with fast agi.

Answer (score 2):

This is already old, but still i got stucked yesterday with same issue, and found the solution.
A lot of people saying about the classpath where your properties file should be, and they are right. 
As long as you running the asterisk jar in terms to run the test script, it doesn't have the properties file inside with YOUR script pointed there. So you need to direct it.
Try to use this command, but modify it with your path:

```
java -cp /home/your user/folder with project/src/main/java/:/home/your user/folder with jar file placed/asterisk-java-2.0.2.jar org.asteriskjava.fastagi.DefaultAgiServer
```

org.asteriskjava.fastagi.DefaultAgiServer - this is the path which you use to run a server. Even if you will write something like:

```
java -jar asterisk-java-2.0.2.jar
```

it will call the DefaultAgiServer anyway.
So my point is, that the classpath here is a keyword, and command above will solve this problem for sure =)

**UPD:** Although it fix the issue with classpath of .properties file, that doesn't mean that it will solve this problem, in case if your script placed in additional packages =)
If path to your script is something like

```
 com.yourcompany.yourpackage.YourScript
```

that mean that you need write down the same thing in a properties. Something like:

```
hello.agi = com.yourcompany.yourpackage.YourScript
```

Hope this will help somebody ;)

Answer (score 0):

This error is writed by your java code. See java code for more info about how to do call. Most likly need do something like

```
AGI://localhost/xxx.agi?function=func
```